# How to convert whole numbers into decimals and the correct syntax for this conversion in SQL

Tags: sql-server, casting, decimal, numeric

I'm trying to turn the results of the code below into decimals but I don't know how to or were to place a command such as "Convert" or "Decimal" in the code. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
select
    system_type_id,
    column_id,
    system_type_id / column_id as calculation
from sys.all_columns
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You should also be showing some evidence that you're tried to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to divide two integers and avoid integer division, I just multiple the numerator by 1.0:

```
select system_type_id, column_id, system_type_id * 1.0 / column_id as calculation
from sys.all_columns
```

I'm not sure why you would do this using ids from a system table, though.

Answer (score 0):

select
    convert(decimal(14,2),system_type_id),
    convert(decimal(14,2),column_id),
    convert(decimal(14,2),system_type_id / column_id) as calculation
from sys.all_columns

NB: the 2 means to 2 decimal place if you want to convert int to decimal